# Trying to kill cron job processes found by "ps ax | grep keyword" logged in as pi user

Tags: raspbian, cron, sudo

I'm trying to kill several processes from the command line logged into the pi as the user pi. All of the processes have been started by cronjobs, so they should belong to the
root user. I'm running the current raspbian.

running **ps ax | grep keyword** results in a long list with pairs like this

```
23157 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c python /home/pi/scripting/keyword_script.py
23162 ?        S      0:00 python /home/pi/scripting/keyword_script.py /home/pi/s
```

I'm looking for the right syntax to kill these, preferably in one command.
If that's not possible, I could also try killing them manually one-by-one.

I tried for the one-by-one approach:

**kill -9 23157** (Error: -bash: kill: (17617) operation not permitted)

**sudo kill -9 23157** (long wait, then error sudo: kill: command not found)

I tried for the kill-all approach:

**pkill -9 keyword** (no error, no kill)

**sudo pkill -9 keyword** (no error, no kill)

Any hints?

Comment: Try adding /bin/ before kill for the sudo approach. You can get the PID directly by doing something like this: `/sbin/kill -9 \`ps ax | grep keyword | awk '{ print $1}'\``

Comment: Thanks, alas the /sbin directory does not have kill in it, so this just gives the error "No such file or directory"

Comment: Thanks, su doesn't exist on the raspian linux, so that doesn't work for me. This is a linux question, but with all the linux dialects around I feel this chance of a working answer is better here.

Comment: Ack, sorry, that should have been `/bin/kill`.

Comment: Tried this with process 23157 by typing "/bin/kill -9 23157". I get the error message "-bash: /bin/kill: Input/output error
" Adding sudo to it gives the familiar "sudo: /bin/kill: command not found" error. Process 23157 is still shown alive when I retry "ps ax"